# Wordpress post to separate table

Tags: php, database, wordpress, post

I'm using the Zion template for wordpress (http://goo.gl/3luXY) and I want to post the sermons to a separate table (sermons) just for the information I want, as well as wherever wordpress posts it to make it work for the template (wp_posts, wp_post_meta, etc.). I have added a few metadata sections in the functions.php file for the template. I want the title too, not just what would be included in the functions.php file.
Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Why would you not use the Posts table?  You can create a [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types) for `sermon`s, rather than subvert all the handy WP functionality.

Comment: Because I want to keep all the sermons in a separate location for future use (i.e. for website change or just for keeping them together).

Comment: If you use a custom post type, you can always export *just* the sermons later. Also, you can get just the sermons using `get_posts()`, `WP_QUery`, or other native WordPress functions/classes.

Comment: But I need the sermon data in a separate table, as well as where wordpress & the template will need them.